# sbt - add unmanaged resources to console

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt, I want to add a `config` directory to the runtime class-path (but not export it as part of `package`). So I have this:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Runtime += baseDirectory.value / "config"
```

This works fine for `sbt run`, but apparently is not on the class-path if I use `sbt console`.

How can I add this directory to the class-path for the `console` task without it showing up in the exported jar?

---

**Edit:** I also tried the following, but I still cannot get the resources:

```
unmanagedClasspath in (Compile, console) += baseDirectory.value / "config"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually adding the following does work:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "config"
```

I had found the contents in `"config"` only because the package was created previously and using `sbt clean package` shows that now the contents of `"config"` will *not* be packaged any longer but do appear on the console class-path.